# Vaadin: How to add Tabs dynamically and give them a view

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm trying to use an "Add" tab to create new Tabs and attach a view to them. In my mind I'd to create something like the Excel sheets: when created, every view is a basic view in which the user can insert data.

I tried this:

```
private void create() {
    tabs = new Tabs();
    plus = new Tab("+");

    plus.getElement().addEventListener("click", e -> {
        addTab();
    });
        
    tabs.add(plus)
        
}

private void addTab() {
    Tab tab = new Tab("New tab");
    RouterLink billview = new RouterLink(BasicView.class);
        
    tab.add(billview);
    tabs.add(tab);
        
}

public class BasicView extends VerticalLayout{
    
    
    public BasicView() {

        TextField text = new TextField("Text");
        add(text);
    }
    
}
```

But this creates tabs that have the same view (link), I want to have different views.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to that question is too much code to be copied here. I have packaged such a thing as a [TabSheet](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tabsheet) add-on component, which can be found at Vaadin's Directory. It is noteworthy to mention here that similar TabSheet component will be included as an official component in Vaadin 23 soon.